# Weird function behaviour (floating point issue)

Tags: python, math

Why does g(x)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = lambda n, d: sum([int(x) for x in str(d)*n])
    g = lambda k: sum([int(f(a,a)/a -1) for a in range(1,k)])/k

    a = [g(x) for x in range(1,100)]
    pyplot.plot(a)
    pyplot.show()
```

Plot this?
[image]

And it gets weirder and if you do

```
    a = [g(i)/float(i) for i in range(1,100)]
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result. When I run your code, I get a smooth curve. Also, what's the point of using `lambda`s when you give them names, anyway?

Comment: what did you expect? you can split calculation smaller parts and use `print()` to check values in these parts - ie. display values for `f()`. Why do you convert to string `str(d)` ?

Comment: Do you use Python 2.7 or Python 3.x? Looks like the former.

Comment: Looks like some floating point issue. `int(f(a,a)/a -1)` could be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you use Python 2.7 where the division operator divides integer numbers with a remainder. Change the definition of `g`:

```
def g(k):
    return sum([int(f(a, a) / float(a) - 1) 
                for a in range(1, k)]) / float(k)
```

[image]